# If statement in each loop did not give me the right answer

Tags: ruby

So I was working through some coderbyte problems, and and one of the problems was to check whether a string contained a and b exactly 3 spaces apart. I eventually got the correct answer, but I was wondering why the foirstcode did not work. Can someone please helpout a ruby noob?

wrong code:

```
def ABCheck(str)

  # code goes here

  str1 = str.downcase.split("")

  a_count = str1.find_all{|i| i == 'a'}

  b_count = str1.find_all{|i| i == 'b'}

  a_idx = []

  b_idx = []

  str1.each_with_index do|letter,idx|
    if letter == 'a'
      a_idx << idx
    elsif letter == 'b'
      b_idx << idx
    end
  end
  a_idx.each do|i|
    if b_idx.include?(i + 4)
      return true
    elsif b_idx.include?(i - 4)
      return true
    else
      return false
    end
  end
end
```

correct code:

```
def ABCheck(str)
  str1 = str.downcase.split("")
  a_count = str1.find_all{|i| i == 'a'}
  b_count = str1.find_all{|i| i == 'b'}
  a_idx = []
  b_idx = []
  c = []
  d = []

  str1.each_with_index do|letter,idx|
    if letter == 'a'
      a_idx << idx
    elsif letter == 'b'
      b_idx << idx
    end
  end
  a_idx.each do|i|
    c << i + 4
    d << i - 4
  end
  compare1 = c & b_idx
  compare2 = d & b_idx

  if compare1 != []
    return true
  elsif compare2 != []
    return true
  else
    return false
  end
end
```

Comment: Just thought I'd point out that this problem is actually pretty easily solvable with one line: `str =~ /a.{3}b/`

Comment: `elsif b_idx.` - what else?

Comment: @Ajedi32, it appears from the asker's "correct code" that he/she is looking for `scan(/a...b|b...a/)`.

Comment: The "correct" code still has a useless calculation of `a_count` and `b_count` which are never used.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a compact alternative answer, but it may require some explanation:

```
def ab_check(s)
  !!(s =~ /a...b|b...a/)
end
```

First, the string `s` is matched against the regex. The first part `a...b` means check for an `a` followed by any three characters then a `b`. The `|` is a logical OR in regex. The final part `b...a` checks for the opposite: a `b` followed by any three characters then an `a`. A regex match returns an index or nil, but you want a true or false. So I force a true/false answer by using a unary `!` (which requires parens because of precedence). This is now the opposite of what we want (true when not matched) so we have to use a second `!`.

Answer (score 0):

Last part of your code should be:

```
a_idx.each do |i|
  if b_idx.include?(i + 4)
    return true
  elsif b_idx.include?(i - 4)
    return true
  end
end
false
```

work for me.